# im having trouble with my python code and the if-then thing

Tags: python, if-statement

ok the problem is, is that im trying to make a if then for a character sheet maker when it askes for gender this is my code

```
gender = input('what gender would you like your character to be? ').capitalize()
if gender == 'Male' or 'Guy' or 'man' or 'Boy' or 'M':
gender = 'He'
elif gender == 'Female' or 'Woman' or 'Girl' or 'Lady' or 'F':
gender = 'She'
else:
gender == ()
gender = 'They'
```

problem is...it only gives back "he" no matter the answer....what am i getting wrong?
thing is...this is what ive learned via w3 and youtube

i have tried different ways to code it...i have even tried making it a def function but nothing seems to work...

Comment: This mistake can be across multiple languages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949030/if-statement-is-always-true-no-matter-what-string-i-pass-in is someone making the same mistake in javascript, for example; whereas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922943/how-to-check-if-variable-equal-to-multiple-values is someone making the same mistake in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you are not using
a comparison it is treated as `True` or `False`. Empty variables, 0, empty arrays, `False` are Treated as `False` in python.

```
if gender == 'Male' or 'Guy' or 'man' or 'Boy' or 'M':
```

In this case your are only comparing  gender with the `male`. And

```
'Guy' or 'man' or 'Boy' or 'M':
```

are Treated as bools(`True`). Therefore gender is always assigned to the 'He' and pass without going to `elif` as There is always something `True` in `If` statement.

There are two ways you can fix this.

```
gender = input('what gender would you like your character to be? ').capitalize()

if gender == 'Male' or gender=='Guy' or gender=='man' or gender=='Boy' or gender=='M':
    gender = 'He'

elif gender == 'Female' or gender=='Woman' or gender=='Girl' or gender=='Lady' or gender=='F':
    gender = 'She'

else:
    gender = 'They'
```

Which is very inconvenient. Second method is,

```
gender = input('what gender would you like your character to be? ').capitalize()

if gender in ['Male','Guy','man', 'Boy', 'M']:
    gender = 'He'
elif gender in ['Female', 'Woman', 'Girl', 'Lady', 'F'] :
    gender = 'She'
else:
    gender = 'They'
```

Comment: Duplicates should be closed, not answered.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `or` operators are not doing what you think.
Consider your `if` statement:

```
if gender == 'Male' or 'Guy' or 'man' or 'Boy' or 'M':
```

It is interpreted as:

```
if (gender == 'Male') or ('Guy') or ('man') or ('Boy') or ('M'):
```

So every time it is returning `True` because the string `Guy` is interpreted as `True`:

```
>>> if 'Guy': print("yes")
yes
```

What you need is the `in` operator:

```
if gender in ['Male', 'Guy', 'man', 'Boy', 'M']:
```

However `guy` will return `They` so you may want to convert `gender` to lowercase:

```
if gender.lower() in ['male', 'guy', 'man', 'boy', 'm']
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".